# Does item duping still work in Diablo 2 with the latest patches (for single player use)?

Tags: diablo-ii, cheats

Once upon a merry time ago I was the first kid on my block to beat Diablo 2 with a Paladin.  One thing that I hated was farming for runes and gems.

We discovered pretty quickly how to use multiplayer mode and a back up of the player file to dupe gems and runes so we could create things like our triple socketed perfect diamond great shield in a lot less than the forever that farming offered.

Has this bug been patched over in the latest patches? (I will follow up with a question about the best way to farm runes/gems that I can use on battle.net)

Comment: Just as a friendly suggestion, you may want to note in the title of this question that you're talking about Single Player and Open B-net, as duping on closed B-net is effectively cheating/hacking, and is not looked well upon. I realize that you qualify the intentions in the body text, but it's not immediately apparent from the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no reason to dupe in Diablo 2 on multiplayer LAN or open battlenet since the characters are saved on your local hard drive and you can download an diablo 2 character editor (there are many) to give yourself whatever you want, even change attributes on items to make them super overpowered.

As for closed battlenet, duping still exists, in particular, high end runes are still often duped on the ladder where they can be used in powerful ladder only rune words.  The reason why runes are the choice for duping is because they cannot 'poof' if they are immediately used in an item for a runeword as they take on the UID of the item they are put in, but if two duped items with the same UID enters a game, they will dissapear.

Comment: As an alternative, you might try the [PlugY](http://plugy.free.fr/en/index.html) mod, which gives you an effectively infinite shared stash.  That way you can pool items among any of your characters, yielding more gems (for instance) than you could possibly need.

Answer (score 3):

There's a really helpful program called [ATMA](http://atma.incgamers.com/) (A Tenshi Muling Application) that allows you to edit the stash of your single-player characters.

I used it to transfer items from one character and to have a big database of items separate from my characters. You can also use it to duplicate items by transferring items from one character to the other, then simply don't save the character file you took the items from -> both characters end up having the items.